# Having a hard time getting started with Vim-R-plugin

Tags: r, vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to install the R-project (for statistics) plugin for VIM, on my PC (using ubuntu).

I have followed the instruction on the plugin [web page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628)

- I have installed the conque shell plug in as well, as requested.
- I have installed the vim-r-plugin
- I have added the 4 needed line to my .vimrc file:

  ```
  set nocompatible
  syntax enable
  filetype plugin on
  filetype indent on
  ```
- I have set my maplocalleader to `,`
- I open a .R file
- I try the command, like `:,rf`,  and I get: `E492: Not an editor command: ,rf`

I don't know really how to trouble shout this problem, or where to find help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, my first answer was out of scope.

You needn't `:` to use mappings. Just hit `,rf`

old answer was:

Usually, vim commands can be prefixed with a line range. Here the `:,` suggests you are indicating a line range.

Valid line ranges might be (not a full list):

- `a` (single line)
- `[a],b` (line ranges)
- `%` (synonym of `1,$`)

`a` and `b` can be replaced with `.` (current line), `$` (last line), any valid line number, `'x` where *x* is a mark, and any arithmetic combination of them.

But `,` alone does not seem to be appropriate in front of a command name.

Also see `:help cmdline-ranges`